# Generate Java Classes from XSD with default package name and XSD namespace

Tags: jaxb, jaxb2-maven-plugin

I have 2 sets of XSDs, One for Inbound operations and other for outbound operations. Both XSD sets have similar namespace but since are from different sources need to be maintained seperately in the same codeset. Each XSD set has deeply nested classes and generates roughly 650 classes. 
I am using a Maven JAXB plugin to generate Java classes. 
If I specify an `<outputDirectory>`, the file generation fails because of namespace collision between Outbound and Inbound operation. If I specify `<packageName>`, all classes are generated in the same package which results in namespace collision within Inbound operations. 
Is there a way in which Maven will follow the package name provided by XSD namespace and prefix the package name with 'inbound' or 'outbound' to seperate the resulting package names. For e.g the packages create by XSD is

```
com.example.operation
com.example.operation.v1
```

Can it be modified to

```
inbound.com.example.operation
inbound.com.example.operation.v1
```

My Maven pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<artifactId>sample-integration-model</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>sample-integration-model</name>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>



        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>xjc-outbound</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>xjc</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>

                        <laxSchemaValidation>true</laxSchemaValidation>
                        <outputDirectory>target/jaxb2/outbound</outputDirectory>
                        <sources>
                            <source>src/main/xsd/OutboundXsd/RequestMessagesDictionary</source>
                            <source>src/main/xsd/OutboundXsd/ResponseMessagesDictionary</source>
                        </sources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>

                <execution>
                    <id>xjc-inbound</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>xjc</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>

                        <laxSchemaValidation>true</laxSchemaValidation>
                        <outputDirectory>target/jaxb2/inbound</outputDirectory>
                        <sources>
                            <source>src/main/xsd/InboundXsd/RequestMessagesDictionary</source>
                            <source>src/main/xsd/InboundXsd/ResponseMessagesDictionary</source>
                        </sources>
                        <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can tell Maven to set the generated classes in a given package.
Use `<generatePackage>desired.package</generatePackage>` inside the `execution` tag.

It is well documented [here](http://www.mojohaus.org/jaxb2-maven-plugin/Documentation/v2.2/example_xjc_basic.html).